# jQuery Select Field count up duplicate entries

Tags: jquery, select, input

i want to add entries from the inputfield into the selectfield, if i insert duplicate entries it should add a number to the already existed value.

My attempt only works with the first entry, the second adds more entries to the select field also it isn't case sensitive, could you help me please?

Also got a jsfiddle ready for you: https://jsfiddle.net/hnxmv1jx/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $anzahl = 1;
  $("#OptionHinzufuegenButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    function doppeleintragcheck() {

      $("#OptionListeFeld > option").each(function() {
        var s = $(this).text();
        var match = $(this).text() == $('#OptionHinzufuegenFeld').val();

        if (match) {
          $(this).text(this.text + '(' + $anzahl + ')');
          $anzahl++;
        } else if (s.indexOf($('#OptionHinzufuegenFeld').val()) >= 0) {
          var t = s.replace(/\((\d+)\)$/, (m, a) => '(' + (++a) + ')');
          $(this).text(t);
        } else {
          $('#OptionListeFeld').append($('<option>', {
            value: $anzahl,
            text: ($("#OptionHinzufuegenFeld").val())
          }));
        }
      });
    }

    if (!$('#OptionListeFeld > option').val()) {

      $('#OptionListeFeld').append($('<option>', {
        value: $anzahl,
        text: ($("#OptionHinzufuegenFeld").val())
      }));
    } else {
      doppeleintragcheck();
    }
  });

  $("#OptionLeerenButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#OptionListeFeld').empty();
    $anzahl = 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <form>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Artikel</legend>
    <!-- OptionHinzufuegenFeld-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="OptionHinzufuegenFeld">Option</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="OptionHinzufuegenFeld" name="OptionHinzufuegenFeld" type="text" placeholder="Option 1" value="Option 1" class="form-control input-md">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Speichern/Absenden -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="SpeichernButton">Optionen</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button id="OptionHinzufuegenButton" name="OptionHinzufuegenButton" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> add</button>
        <button id="OptionLeerenButton" name="OptionLeerenButton" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optionsliste-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="OptionListeFeld">Optionsliste</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="OptionListeFeld">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is adding it again when you have more than one option is because you have this loop `$("#OptionListeFeld > option").each(function()` for options. So when you have `option 1` then for that case it goes in else part and adds the option even though you already have `option 2` in `select`. And when `option 2` comes it increases value and thus you see it two times.

Why I added `return false`. If you add `option 1` and then adds `option 2` and then again adds `option 1` it will be added again coz of again same thing.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var $anzahl = 1;
  var existOpt = false;
  $("#OptionHinzufuegenButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    function doppeleintragcheck() {

      $("#OptionListeFeld > option").each(function() {
        existOpt = false;
        var s = $(this).text();
        var match = $(this).text() == $('#OptionHinzufuegenFeld').val();

        if (match) {
          $(this).text(this.text + '(' + $anzahl + ')');
          $anzahl++;
          existOpt = true;//element found;
          return false; //get out of loop when element found
        } else if (s.indexOf($('#OptionHinzufuegenFeld').val()) >= 0) {
          var t = s.replace(/\((\d+)\)$/, (m, a) => '(' + (++a) + ')');
          $(this).text(t);
          existOpt = true;//element found;
          return false; //get out of loop when element found
        } 
      });
       if(!existOpt) {//add if element not found;
                    $('#OptionListeFeld').append($('<option>', {
                        value: $anzahl,
                        text: ($("#OptionHinzufuegenFeld").val())
                    }));
                }
    }

    if (!$('#OptionListeFeld > option').val()) {

      $('#OptionListeFeld').append($('<option>', {
        value: $anzahl,
        text: ($("#OptionHinzufuegenFeld").val())
      }));
    } else {
      doppeleintragcheck();
    }
  });

  $("#OptionLeerenButton").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#OptionListeFeld').empty();
    $anzahl = 1;
  });
});
```

```html
<fieldset>
  <form>
    <!-- Form Name -->
    <legend>Artikel</legend>
    <!-- OptionHinzufuegenFeld-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="OptionHinzufuegenFeld">Option</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <div class="input-group">
          <input id="OptionHinzufuegenFeld" name="OptionHinzufuegenFeld" type="text" placeholder="Option 1" value="Option 1" class="form-control input-md">
          <div class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"></i></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Speichern/Absenden -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="SpeichernButton">Optionen</label>
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <button id="OptionHinzufuegenButton" name="OptionHinzufuegenButton" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span> add</button>
        <button id="OptionLeerenButton" name="OptionLeerenButton" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span> clear</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Optionsliste-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="OptionListeFeld">Optionsliste</label>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <select multiple class="form-control" id="OptionListeFeld">
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</fieldset>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
```

Comment: @chim Glad I helped :)